# How to access global telerik functions in typescript

Tags: asp.net, typescript, telerik

I try to access the function **GetRadWindowManager()** from my app.ts file.

I added the definitions files and I cannot find a way to call "window.GetRadWindowManager()" or "window.top.GetRadWindowManager()"

That is my code until now :

```
export class App {
    private _windowManager: Telerik.Web.UI.RadWindowManager;

    constructor() {
        this._windowManager = null;
    }

    getRadWindowManager(): Telerik.Web.UI.RadWindowManager {

        if (this._windowManager == null) {
            try {
                this._windowManager = window.top.GetRadWindowManager();
            } catch (err) {
                this._windowManager = GetRadWindowManager();
            }
        }

        return this._windowManager;
    }
}
```

PS : Don't mind the try/catch block, I'll remove that later :)

Thanks for your help !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I don't know if this answer is the best, but extending the Window object allowed me to manually add this function. Then I can simply call it from my script.ts

```
interface Window {
    GetRadWindowManager(): Telerik.Web.UI.RadWindowManager;
}
```